# Trying to get response.name or id

Tags: javascript, facebook

On my page, people can press a share button and post on Facebook. 
I use this code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init(
    {
        "appId"  : "<?php echo $fbid; ?>",
        "status" : true,
        "cookie" : true,
        "xfbml"  : true,
        "oauth"  : true
    });
```

On click the function showStreamPublish starts:

```
function showStreamPublish() {
        FB.ui(
           {
             method: 'feed',
             name: 'Text',
             caption: 'Text',
             link: 'Link',
             picture:'Pic',
             description: 'ni',
             user_message_prompt: 'Share it!'

           },
           function(response) {
                 if (response && response.post_id) {



                    FB.api('/me', function(response) 
        {alert(response.name);
        });  ...
```

Where I use the following Code I wanna  show the Username of the person who did the Sahre but it doesnt :(

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) 
        {alert(response.name);
        });
```

How can I get the Username or the UserID of the persob who did the Share? 
It opens the Alert-Box - with "undefined" as content.
Thank you for help.

I tried to get the response.status and the weird thing is: Even if I connect through my app and post on Facebook, I get the message that I`m not connectet through my app. Using that Code:

```
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app
    alert('All good');
    }else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
   // the user is logged in but NOT through your app
   alert('Not good');
   }else{
    alert('What the heck?');// the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Neil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook function(response)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15427821/facebook-functionresponse)

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that I don't feel are good:

- the `FB.api` call is included into `FB.ui`.
- you use `response` twice:

  - `FB.ui({...}, function(response) {...`,
  - `FB.api('/me', function(response) {...`.

Both problems may be related or not. But this would make it:

```
function showUserName() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert('Post was published by ' + response.name);
    });
}
function showStreamPublish() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Text',
        caption: 'Text',
        link: 'Link',
        picture: 'Pic',
        description: 'ni',
        user_message_prompt: 'Share it!'
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            showUserName();
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thx so far. But even here I get "Post was published by undefined". I do not use more code and the post at Facebook is successfull.

Comment: Its weird, still getting: Post was published by undefined. I dont know why! The app has access to the user data, the user is connected and the post is successfull!

Comment: Are you sure it's a real user account and not a business account which won't have a name? If it's a business account that account will always be brought to their list of pages when they log in, can't admin apps or contact other users, etc

Comment: (Either that or you've never actually logged the user in, but i'm assuming you have and that the user ID is present elsewhere in our code)

Comment: If the user is alredady connected to facebook I get the username after the post was done - but if he has to connect through my app I get "undefined" for the username.